# Using C# to kill some threads in svchost.exe process, but not all of its threads

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, unmanaged, managed

I'm working on a problem with a memory leak. Somewhere in a large codebase, there are some unmanaged resources (maybe network connections) that are not being garbage collected fast enough. My system eventually runs out of memory because of a huge number of OS handles / svchost.exe threads. It's only one svchost.exe process in particular that keeps growing. So I've attempted to target the biggest svchost.exe thread and kill it with force. I'm able to do so, and it works just fine for a while, but I'm noticing that sometimes the network connectivity drops. I think it's because as the app runs, it's adding threads to svchost.exe but so is some other background process. Eventually, the svchost.exe process in question probably includes threads for other applications, perhaps for the OS networking functionality, and killing it kills those threads too.

Is there a way to limit the threads that I kill after picking the svchost.exe process I want to kill? Is my best bet to debug the entire codebase and hope to find the spot where the memory leak is happening? My manager's suggestion on where to look didn't turn up any real information, and none of the engineers before me were able to figure it out with monitoring tools, so I'm wondering if it's time to just sit down with the debugger for a few hours during the weekend.

I'm currently trying to get the garbage collector to forcefully collect all generation 1 objects, but it isn't helping with the thread count. The svchost.exe in question slowly but surely grows in thread count and handle count.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, this is not the solution

Comment: “Is my best bet to debug the entire codebase and hope to find the spot where the memory leak is happening?” **Yes.** Killing threads in other processes to stop memory leaks is horribly wrong.

Comment: Why not? Is it a bad idea to kill svchost.exe? Any suggestions on how to track down a memory leak? There are a few processes for the application I'm running but their thread counts remain stable. Meanwhile, one svchost.exe process's thread count goes up. So some part of my codebase is making that happen, but I'm not sure how to find out which part.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Is it just a bad practice? Or is it probable that it'll introduce more errors?

Comment: A memory leak will just grow and your app will explode eventually. Forcing garbage collection is just useless if you have memory leaks. Find and solve the memory leak is your only option in this case.

Comment: @Sievajet May the C# gods have mercy on my tiny soul.

Comment: Use a memory profiler to find your memory leak, you can even use the diagnostics tools from visual studio 2015 to trackdown the objects that been kept alive

Comment: What is "the biggest thread"? A thread is a kernel mode structure and always has the same size. Threads and memory are not related. If you kill a thread, the memory will still be there.